# Cookies en Array con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, javascript-objeto, js-cookie

estoy avanzando mis conocimientos y me he topado con las cookies en JS, lo que quiero hacer es las típicas 3 funciones de creación, edición y borrado. Pero el caso es que al crear y editar las cookies necesito guardarlas en un array multidimensional (N posiciones con X valores) y al editarlas quiero editar le quiero pasar el el valor que se va a editar y la función sería para N posiciones del array (Ya que puede tener X valores el Array). Las funciones que he realizado no son suficientes puesto que me devuelven el Array de la cookie pero no buscan dentro de él el valor.

Quiero hacer algo parecido a esto:

---

```
var animals = [
   ["cat", ["color", "brown"] ],
   ["dog", ["color", "white"] ],
];
```

---

**Aclaración**: Quiero recorrer el mismo array y todo su interior y buscar X valor dentro de N.

```js
var animals = [
    ["cat", ["color", "brown"] ],
    ["dog", ["color", "white"] ],
];

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++){
  console.log('El resultado del array es: ['+animals[i]+']');
  for (var j = 0; j < animals[i].length; j++){
    console.log(('El animal '+animals[i][j]) + ' tiene los siguientes valores: ' + animals[i][j]); 
  }
}
```

```
Pero el output que quiero que sea: 
1º - El resultado del array es: [cat,color,brown]
2º - 
     El animal cat tiene los siguientes valores: [color, brown]
     El animal cat tiene los siguientes valores: [color, white]
```

---

**Me disculpo de antemano si me he equivocado al escribir algo o si no está claro. Si necesitáis más dudas encantado respondo.**

Comment: No se entiende lo que pretendes. Lo que muestras en código se asemeja más a PHP y no a Javascript. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y agrega más detalles a tu pregunta, mostrando un [mcve], donde se vea lo que has intentado, el comportamiento actual y el resultado esperado. También te invito a leer [ask]. Saludos

Comment: No logro comprender del todo, pero creo que te refieres a colocar dentro de un Array otro Array y en ese anidado colocar propiedades?... si es asi te puedo dar un ejemplo, responde a estecomentario si te refieres a ello...

Comment: @MauricioContreras Hola Mauricio, creo que así queda más claro. My bad por haberlo puesto como PHP es la costumbre, no se si así te quedará mas claro. Saludos

Comment: @Himeno-Chan Hola si, he actualizado para aclarar algo más (espero jaja). Quisiera por ejemplo cambiar el atributo "color" con el valor "brown" de "cat" a "red" por ejemplo.

Comment: @Himeno-Chan y si me gustaría ver tu ejemplo me podría ayudar gracias un saludo

Comment: Bien, hare un ejemplo rapido delo que quieres hacer, aun asi para ello puedes crear objetos o clases y extenderlas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gracias por responderme, he conseguido mi meta**

Aquí no funciona pero si lo probáis en Local o fuera de Stack **funciona**

```js
var mySettings = {
        settings : {
            lang:  'en',
            location:   'home',
            event:   false,
        }
    };

 $(document).ready(function(){

            /* - - - - - - - - */
            var web = Cookies.get('web');
            /* - - - - - - - - */
            if(!web){
                Cookies.set('web', JSON.stringify(mySettings));
                window.location.reload();
            }else{
                // Parse Web Array JSON
                web = JSON.parse(web);
                // Set each variable for each setting value
                var lang = web.settings.lang;
                var location = web.settings.location;
                var event = web.settings.event;
                // Print cookie values on select
                $("#lang option[value="+lang+"]").attr('selected', 'selected');
                $("#location option[value="+location+"]").attr('selected', 'selected');
            }

            $('#lang').on('change', function() {
                var selLang = $(this).val();
                if(web){
                    web.settings.lang = selLang;
                    Cookies.set('web', JSON.stringify(web));
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });

            $('#location').on('change', function() {
                var selLocation = $(this).val();
                if(web){
                    web.settings.location = selLocation;
                    Cookies.set('web', JSON.stringify(web));
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
form{
            text-align: center;
        }
        input[type="text"], select{
            width: 40%;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
            border-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 25px;
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
        }
        input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color:  black;
            padding: 16px 32px;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
        }
        input[type=button]:hover, input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=reset]:hover{
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <h2>Cambia tus Cookies</h2>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="data-select">
            <div class="settings">
                <label for="lang"><i class="fas fa-language"></i></label>
                <select id="lang" name="lang">
                    <option value = "en" selected>EN</option>
                    <option value = "es">ES</option>
                    <option value = "it">IT</option>
                </select>
                <label for="location"><i class="fas fa-language"></i></label>
                <select id="location" name="location">
                    <option value = "home" selected>Inicio</option>
                    <option value = "menu">Menu</option>
                    <option value = "about">Sobre Nosotros</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2.2.1/src/js.cookie.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const animals = [
    { name: 'cat', color: ['white', 'brown'] },
    { name: 'dog', color: ['white', 'black'] }
]

animals.forEach(animal => {
    console.log(
        `El resultado del array es: ${animal.name}\n`,
        `El animal ${animal.name} tiene las siguientes propiedades: ${animal.color}`
    )
})
```

Aqui tienes un pequeño ejemplo de como podrias hacerlo con un forEach y objetos simples... pero aqui tienes otro pequeño ejemplo de como seria con el metodo que tu quieres implementar.

```js
const animals = [
    ["cat", ["color", "brown"] ],
    ["dog", ["color", "white"] ],
];

for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    let member = animals[i]
    let name = member[0]
    let options = member[1]
    console.log(`El resultado del array es: ${member}\n\n`)
    console.log(`El animal ${name} tiene las siguientes opciones ${options}\n\n`)
}
```